# MYSQL date comparison not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I have column in table with type as timestamp, I have 2 records in database one with value "2014-07-12 23:10:15" and other with "2013-06-01 01:10:12"

And now quering table like but i am returned with empty result :

```
SELECT comments.* FROM tbl_product_comments as comments WHERE DATE(comments.created_date) BETWEEN 2010-06-01 AND 2014-07-13
```

And Also this way, but again getting empty result

```
SELECT comments.* FROM tbl_product_comments as comments WHERE DATE(comments.created_date) > 2010-06-01 AND DATE(comments.created_date) < 2014-07-13
```

Can any one please tell me, why i am not getting result and what will be the correct query.

Thanks..

Comment: '2010-06-01' AND '2014-07-13'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your date literals with quotes.

```
 BETWEEN '2010-06-01' AND '2014-07-13'
```

Your original code is being parsed as arithmetic expressions.

2010-06-01 = 2003

2014-07-13 = 1994

Example. This returns data:

```
select * from tab where 2009 between 2010-01-01 and 2014-01-01
```

evaluates to

```
select * from tab where 2009 between 2008 and 2012
```